# Composite Null hypothesis in a Linear Regression

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, least-squares, composite

Suppose that we have an OLS estimator $\hat{\beta}$.

Also, assume that we know $\hat{\beta}\sim N(\beta, \Omega)$ and have an estimator for $\Omega$, say $\hat{\Omega}$.

Here, I want to test the following composite null hypothesis:
$$H_0:\quad M\beta\geq0 \qquad H_1:\quad M\beta<0$$

where M is a constant vector of proper dimension such that $M\beta$ is a scalar.

In this situation, how can I test the null hypothesis using $\hat{\beta}$ and $M\hat{\Omega}M'$?

(where $M\hat{\Omega}M'$ is the variance of $M\hat{\beta})$

Is the usual t-test is possible?

Comment: You mean, I can test the "composite" null hypothesis based on a t statistic??

Comment: No. Just the simple null hypothesis. I misread your question.

Comment: This is a special case of the *general linear hypothesis* test (a search here turns up many relevant posts), and in this case where the linear combination of coefficients is a scalar, you should be able to get a t-test and be able to test the one-sided alternative. You should have that $t^2=F$ where $F$ is the usual glht F-statistic.